# DDoS vulnerable forms

Tags: php, security, ddos

I recently heard that a website can be DDoS'ed through the those doing the attack submitting forms with i.e 2MB data (in characters), lot's of times very rapidly. Is this statement true? If so, is there anything I can do in PHP to prevent this, i.e set the form data limit down?

Comment: I do not think you can do much against DDOSing by changing your forms.
Because DDOSing is in most cases sending millions of millions of requests to crash the server by overloading it.
DDOSing in its simple form does not abuse any weaknesses in your forms/design it just tries to send more requests than the server can bare regardless of your form.

Comment: You can look at using a session to count how many times a user has submitted this form in a given session. If it's over a certain amount, then just `exit()` to save your server doing any more processing. Of course this still requires *some* processing, so it's not a solution.

Comment: Do you mean DoS ? I dont see the First D in DDoS here

Answer (score 1):

DDoS'ing by submitting large amounts of data would require some vulnerability in data processing, otherwise it is not really plausible since the attackers upload speed becomes a bigger factor. It would be much easier to attack with using [slowloris](http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/) or ping floods.

Using data an outdated server can be DDoS'ed by using variable parsing problem aka the Hash Collision attack (not only PHP). It is discussed on the 28th Chaos Communication Congress which can be watched [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2Cq3CLI6H8).

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than 1 thing that was going on in the background that would have led to this DoS. I am assuming the OP is using DDoS instead of just DoS. Anyway, the reasons why this could have happened are because, the code spent too much time on a single request, too much logging(ie the server writes to the log every-time it gets a bad request) or a plain old bottleneck on the server side. And I believe 2 MB is a moderate size for a POST request. If going below that doesn't affect your functionality, go ahead and reduce it.

See my question here, which is along the same lines : https://serverfault.com/questions/413718/tomcat-denial-of-service-due-to-large-packets